# RxJS - Subscribe/Unsubscribe vs filter() operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a spinner component written in Angular. If the spinner component is active, i.e. spinner is running, then I need a subscription to the window.scroll event to do some position calculations.

I'm wondering if it is a good idea to always create the subscription when spinner is running and unsubscribe if the spinner is no longer running. 
Or if it is better if I create the subscription once when the component gets initialized and work with the filter operator, to go into subscribe() when the spinner is active. And just unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed.

My current implementation works with the filter:

```
this.scroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll');
this.scrollSubscription = this.scroll$
    // continue only if the spinner is active
    .pipe(filter(() => this.isActive))
    .subscribe(_e => {
        this.doSomeStuff();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way should work fine in most applications, but it will depend on a couple things to determine most efficient method.

The main one is how often you'd subscribe/unsubscribe to the `.scroll` event. If you're only showing this spinner once every minute or two (and only need to watch events then) I'd recommend doing a full subscribe and unsubscribe even if the component isn't destroyed since this will minimize the number of events you need to watch, but if the spinner will be appearing every few seconds you will definitely want to just filter the events and unsubscribe on component destroy.

Both of these are fairly low cost as far as processing goes, so there will likely be minimal effect regardless of the route you choose.